# Basic implementation of buffered I/O

Tags: c, linux, d, glibc

I'm creating a custom buffered I/O library for D (removing C dependence). I have looked at the source of libc, and managed to find `_IO_file_xsputn`. But I'm not sure where to go from there. From what I can see, it checks the input length and copies data into the buffer. But I am not sure where to go from there. Is there a pseudocode-like expression of how buffered I/O is implemented? This is my guess to a buffered `puts`-like function:

```
if (buf.length - pos /* available space */  < data.length) {
    flush
    syscall::write the whole input data
} else {
    add data to buf (memcpy, pos += data.length)
    if (data contains '\n')
        flush upto '\n' // Maybe whole buffering instead?
}
```

Comment: This is bassically what happens. This is such easy task, i guess no "pseudocode" exists. Just read simpler libc implementations, like newlib, like code [here](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/wbuf.c#72), is quite exactly the same as yours (ie. check for full buffer then flush, add char to buffer, if buffer full or line buffering and newline, then flush).

Comment: Thanks! My mind melted trying to understand libc, and this simplifies it down a lot.
@JonathanLeffler: D uses the C library for everything, which is why I'm making my own thing.

Comment: you can write an answer for yourself that explains what is going on for future people to read if they land on this from a web search

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use libio as an example for anything.  This code was written in the mid-90s with the intent to share it with the C++ run-time library (libstdc++).  As a result, the code is written in a strange style, basically a manual translation of the C++ `streambuf` classes.  We are now stuck with it for ABI compatibility reasons, so that people can run their really, really old C++ software (and they still do).

The sad part is that the C++ ABI has moved on and has changed several times in incompatible ways since then, before finally settling on the C++ Itanium ABI (which is still incompatible with what we have in glibc)..